# To Customize primeng Calendar Component in angular 2

Tags: css, angular, calendar

I followed the steps to include  component in my angular2 project and able to do this. Now, I want to customize the appearance of the Calendar. Is there any other way to Customize the appearance of this calendar apart from overriding the CSS from our application module.

Or is there any other more suitable customizable component that can be used?